Enabling Developer mode and USB debug
I have an old Nexus 7 2013 tablet. It had virtually stopped working, so I did a factory reset. When I boot up it now goes into the Google startup screen and then to setting up a new account.
It connects to WiFi but then at the next stage says Google play services has failed. I can't get past this stage.
So I thought I would install Lineage OS. How can I enable Developer mode and USB debugging without a working Android system?
When I connect with a USB cable to a PC, the PC doesn't recognize it. It charges but it doesn't show up on the PC as being attached. When I run adb devices on the PC it runs but shows no devices attached. I've checked the cable using another device and that shows up on my PC.
Is there a way to get my original Android system working or turn on Developers mode and USB debug so I can install LineageOS or some other OS?


Try to start without WiFi as the Google Services no longer support Lollipop (5.x) and you may be stuck in a loop trying to connected to servers which won't respond. 1b) You may need to do the old 'skip setup' to get into settings for developer mode. 2) Hopefully you do have a 2013 model as the 2012 model had a flash memory issue but anything that old may still have both battery and memory wear problems so don't be surprised by crashing or memory loss.

